# Unbounded on every interval except null set but finite a.e

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This question originates from Folland's problem 2.25. In this problem, first given $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ when $0<x<1$, and $0$ otherwise.Then consider $g(x)=\sum_{n}2^{-n}f(x-r_{n})$, where sequence $r_{n}$ is the all the rational number. Then it requires us to prove $g$ is integrable, discontinuous everywhere and unbounded on every interval. We need to show that discontinuity and unboundedness hold even removing a Lebesgue null set.

While I can show $g$ is integrable(thus finite a.e.),unboundedness on every interval. I have doubts about why $g$ is finite a.e. Consider any irrational number $x$, there always exist a sequence of $r_{n}$ such that $x-r_{n}<3^{-2n}$, so that $2^{-n}f(x-r_{n})>(3/2)^{n}$. This shows the unboundedness of $g$, however since this holds for any irrational number,this function should not be finite a.e. as $\sum_{n}(3/2)^{n}=\infty$ for every irrational number $x$, thus not finite a.e.

I know there must be something wrong in my argument, but I can't spot it. Can anyone tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your argument is your $r_n$ is different from the $r_n$'s in the definition of $g$. You have to arrange all rationals in a  sequence $(r_n)$ once and for all before defining $g$.

Comment: If I really do so(rearrange all the $r_{n}$), then $g$ is still finite a.e. and unbounded, right?

Comment: I guess boundedness of $g$ depends the particular arrangement of rationals. In your argument you will get $g(x) >\frac {3^{n}} {2^{m}}$ where $m$ depends on $n$ and you have no idea in what way $m$ is related to $n$. So $\frac {3^{n}} {2^{m}}$  can actually be small.  @Ken.Wong